# Eclipse project not added to the build path

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I have Project A with a dependency on project B and project B with a dependency on project A.  Project B compiles and runs and I can see in the properties of the debug that Project A is in the classpath.  When I try to run Project A, I don't see Project B, or another third party external JAR library.  The error I get is "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException".  I have set Windows-Preferences-Building-Build Path Problems-Circular Dependencies to warnings, as recommended in another answer.  This was working recently, although I had to reimport my projects for another reason and I can't get it to work now.

Comment: You really, really, should avoid circular dependencies like this. You can have more than one Java Application launcher from a single project, so why not just have a single project?

Comment: @nitind, I have an API that will be used by two applications.  I guess I should take out the common code to a third project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a project the same way, didn't know about the cycle. To avoid this problem, as an alternative I created a maven project, with a parent pom, in which i declared the two seperate projects A and B as child projects. Then you can add the projects in the pom-file as dependencies. Maybe its a solution to your project, to use Maven as build tool.